# Programmatically removing CSS class files - jQuery

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I am using the `jQueryUI` library to take advantage of tabs on my page and the CSS styles of the tabs are being applied to the content within the `div` tags.

When I use the Chrome Developer tools I have narrowed it down to the following CSS classes in in the jquery-ui.css class:

```
.ui-widget {
    /*font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;*/
    font-size: 1.1em/*{fsDefault}*/;
}
.ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

How do I remove these CSS styles from my `div` content containers.  I tried the following jQuery snippet and it did not work.

```
$("#nameSearch").removeClass("ui-widget");
```

Here is a snippet of my HTML page:

```
<div id="searchTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#nameSearch">Name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#caseNumberSearch">Case Number</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="nameSearch">
        <b>First Name:</b>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstNameSearch" runat="server" CssClass="txt" /><br />
        <b>Last Name:</b>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastNameSearch" runat="server" CssClass="txt" /><br />
        <b>Date of Birth:</b>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateOfBirth" runat="server" CssClass="txt" /><br />
    </div>
    <div id="caseNumberSearch">
        <b>Case Number:</b>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtCaseNumberSearch" runat="server" CssClass="txt" /><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your approach is correct.  Hard to help much though since your HTML snippet doesn't have the jquery UI classes assigned.

Comment: Perhaps you should instead make your `div` styles more specific? `.ui-widget div` should be enough.

Comment: Uh, remove the offending styles from the CSS you are including? Or also include your own CSS that overrides them?

Comment: I guess, the class is being assigned after your HTML is rendered?

Comment: Perhaps you're running your script BEFORE the .ui classes are applied.

Comment: All good points.  The one thing that stands out to me is the second class labeled with the same name twice.  How does is that CSS style applied to the page?

Comment: @Madbreaks - I did not apply CSS classes to my div tags cause I was assuming that it would use the default styles applied in the application CSS file

Answer (score 0):

If you know the position of those CSS rules, then:

**IE**

```
document.styleSheets[0].removeRule(i);

//i = position of the rule.
```

**Other Browsers**

```
document.styleSheets[0].deleteRule(i);
```